# ms sql разворот таблицы

Tags: sql, запрос-в-запросе, pivot

Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64) Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

```
SELECT
  terminalDto.name AS terminal,
  turnoutLog.staff,
  CAST(turnoutLog.dateOpened AS date) AS date
FROM turnoutLog
  INNER JOIN terminalDto ON turnoutLog.id_terminal = terminalDto.id
  INNER JOIN employees ON turnoutLog.id_employees = employees.id
WHERE employees.name = 'Горбунова Кристина Андреевна'
```

Данный запрос выводит таблицу :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Моя задача сделать так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде с помощью PIVOT это как то возможно, но эксперименты не привели к результату.

Comment: [связанный вопрос из англоязычной версии SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  terminalDto.name AS terminal,
  turnoutLog.staff,
  CAST(turnoutLog.dateOpened AS date) AS date
into #Test
FROM turnoutLog
  INNER JOIN terminalDto ON turnoutLog.id_terminal = terminalDto.id
  INNER JOIN employees ON turnoutLog.id_employees = employees.id
WHERE employees.name = 'Горбунова Кристина Андреевна'

select 
    [terminal],sum(staff)[staff],[date]
into #TestPivot
from #Test
group by [terminal],[date]

select @Dates = stuff((select ',' + '[' + left(convert(nvarchar,[date],120),10) + ']'
from #TestPivot
order by [date]
for xml path('')),1,1,'')

SELECT @SqlCode = 
'
select [terminal],'+ @Dates +'
from #TestPivot
pivot
(
sum([staff])
for [date]
in ('+ @Dates +') 
)
as pvt
order by [terminal]
'
select @SqlCode

exec sp_executesql @SqlCode

drop table #Test,#TestPivot
```

Comment: Не понял вашей рекомендации

Comment: А как динамический PIVOT организовать по этому примеру?

Comment: @Max внес изменения, но это конечно не полная динамика, а только ее часть чтобы при появлении новых дат не писать их в код руками.